# Kotlinx Serialization @Body converter error while using HashMap with Any type

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am using `Kotlinx Serialization` with `Retrofit` and try to send params at `Body` via `HashMap` like below

```
@POST("post")
suspend fun sendPost(@Body params : HasMap<String, @Contextual @RawValue Any>) : GenericResponse<Post>
```

But it gives this error message

```
Unable to create @Body converter for java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> (parameter #1)
```

I also add `SerializersModule` to `Retrofit` but it did not help

```
fun provideRetrofit(baseUrl : String, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient) : Retrofit {
    val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
    val json = Json {
        serializersModule = SerializersModule {
            contextual(String.serializer())
            contextual(Int.serializer())
            contextual(Double.serializer())
            contextual(Boolean.serializer())
        }
    }
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
        .build()
}
```

Anyone can help?

```
Kotlinx Version 1.0.1

Kotlinx Converter Version 0.8.0

Kotlin Version 1.4.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/746) we are not able to do this